# Close jQuery Modal Dialog on Form Submit

Tags: jquery

I have a modal dialog which has a form. When a user clicks the submit button on the dialog, I want the form to be submitted, and it works fine. I am using ajax request, hence using **return false;** in the submit. Here's my code:

```
    $("#new_account_class").live("submit", function(){
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        return false;
    });
```

Now, I want the dialog to be closed within the same event. The problem is that, anything I write after **return false;** is not executed, and I cannot close the dialog before the **return false**. But there must be a way out, can anyone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#new_account_class").live("submit", function(){
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function(){
     //this callback is executed upon success full form submission close modal here

  }, "script");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: One question, the first time I open the dialog box and submit, it closes, if i open it again, it does not close on submit. Any idea?

Comment: can you post the code how you are closing the modal, also it is advice-able to make a new question so that if i am not able to help may be somebody else will

Comment: I actually found a solution, I would need to remove the html element by $('#dialog-form').remove(); as #dialog-form already existed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you add code after '$.post(...'? Example:

```
$("#new_account_class").live("submit", function(){
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
    myModal.close(); //example code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ya, this works, but the function returns true, hence my controller action that follows create is executed, and a redirect occurs. I don't want redirection. The other answer works. Thanks for the help.